# Flip side of Feynman's trick for Integration

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

If I differentiate the integral:
$$\int_{-a+2}^{a-2} \ (a-x) \, da$$

then I get 4 - 2 a.

1) Is it possible to get back to integral in the form $ \int_{-a+2}^{a-2} \ (a-x) \, da$?

The application would be to find a way to use the 'flip side of Feynman's trick' described on page 90 and 91. The author Paul J. Nahin of Inside Interesting Integrals appears to find the integral that when integrated again (double integration) leads to the solution. So I thought if one differentiated the original definite integral one could find what the integral should be.  Otherwise the integral seems to have to be guessed.

To illustrate what I'm getting at, so he finds:

$$\int_{0}^{1}   \frac{x^a-1}{\ln(x)}\,dx\,=ln(a+1)\, a > 0, \, a = 0$$

by using:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \ x^y  dy\, = \frac{x^a-1}{\ln(x)}\,$$

So I thought could one differentiate

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^a+1}{\ln(x)} \, dx\, a > 0, \, a = 0$$

to get:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \ x^y  dy\,$$

because without him saying so I cannot see how one could guess this integral.

Hence the question 1.

Comment: no, if you differentiate that first integral in $x$ you get zero

Comment: @qbert maybe I've formated it wrong? using mathematica it confirms  the result code: D[\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(\(-a\) + 2\), \(a - 
    2\)]\(\((a - x)\) \[DifferentialD]a\)\), x]

Comment: you probably want to differentiate in $a$...

Comment: okay I've change it to a, hopefully it makes slightly more sense now!

Comment: now it does not make sense, see the answer below about dummy variables. I think you wanted the original integral with a derivative in $a$

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is a *bound* (also called *dummy*) variable. You can use any other variable except $a$
$$
\int_{-a+2}^{a-2}\ (a-x)\,dx =
\int_{-a+2}^{a-2}\ (a-z)\,dz = \cdots
$$
In any case, your integral *only depends of $a$*.

Edit:
$$
\frac{d}{da}\int_0^1\frac{x^a - 1}{\ln(x)}\,dx\,=
\int_0^1 x^a\,dx
$$
Are you mixing Leibniz rule (the kernel of Feynman's trick) with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: okay thank you that answers the first part...I've change the error so the rest makes more sense now.

Comment: @onepound, your correction is... correct but *very confusing*. Better don't use as integration variable *any* variable used in another place.

Comment: @onepound i also don't see how it is going to give you the answer you proposed. Namely, the answer should have an $x$ in it

Comment: @qbert I think Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla comment in the answer about mixing Leibniz rule (the kernel of Feynman's trick) with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus might be my problem. I might be better off asking the question separetely about Feynman's trick.

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla I think your are right about confusing Feynman's trick with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Both are useful but need to be used properly. 
Somehow in the following link they managed to do this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289119/understanding-limits-that-occur-in-integrals-during-feynmann-integration?rq=1